# Removing referenced libraries from project Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to get Android Studio to work with library dependencies for my project, I am using Android Studio 0.4.0.

I've removed the dependecies from the project structure dialogue, from the settings.gradle and from the build.gradle and also from my project.iml file.

I then delete the directories of the referenced libraries from my main project, but after a few seconds, the referenced library directory reappears but only contains mylibrary.iml file. Everytime I delete it, it reappears again.

Also when Android Studio loads it displays an error stating that non gradle projects can't be referenced from gradle projects but I no longer want them referenced but somehow I can't get rid of them.

The project was imported into Android Studio from an Export from Eclipse.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, clicking on the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button should clear up problems, but if they persist, you can close Android Studio, delete all the `.idea` folders and `.iml` files in your project and re-import.

Comment: Thanks I deleted the .idea and .iml folders as suggested and just running the gradle sync didn't have any effect. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, if you are testing on a device, make sure to uninstall the previously installed app.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official bug on improving this for Android Studio. It includes a bigger description of the problem and a workaround suggested by one of the Android Studio engineers:

Bug description - click on the star button to follow it:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61510

Google Engineer suggested workaround (note that some of the bugs described are fixed):
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61510#c3